# In iPhone Safari, why put some Chinese-English mixed text in table result layout broken. And use webkit browser will not

Tags: html, safari, html-table

In iPhone Safari, why put some Chinese-English mixed or only English text in table result layout broken. And use other browser (ex. chrome) or only Chinese character will not.

**In iPhone Safari**
[image]

**In Orther Browser**

[image]

```css
#product-detail {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 3vw;
    height: auto;
}
#product-detail #product-detail-desc{
    height: auto;
    line-height: 60px;
}
#product-detail table {
    margin-top: 3vw;
}

#product-detail td {
    font-size: 32px;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#product-detail th {
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #777777;
    font-size: 32px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="product-detail">
        <img src="${rsUrl }${productImg.resouceUrl }" class="product-img">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

            <tr>
                <th width="160">商品名稱:</th>
                <td><span>${product.cnName }</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>所屬企業:</th>
                <td>${product.company.cnName }</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>零售地址:</th>
                <td>${product.sellingStation}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>產品介紹:</th>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
  </div>
```